# Clicking on WPF ToggleButton changes other ToggleButtons values

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple ToggleButton with Style triggers to change the button's image based on the state of IsChecked.  This is working fine for one button.  However when I add more than one button to a grid, clicking one of the ToggleButtons changes the state of the others.  Should I use some other trigger type instead of one based on the botton's style?

**Here is the xaml block to lay out the three ToggleButtons:**

```xml
   <Grid Height="362" Width="259">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource TogglebuttonStyle}" IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True"
              Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource TogglebuttonStyle}" IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True"
              Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <ToggleButton Style="{StaticResource TogglebuttonStyle}" IsChecked="{x:Null}" IsThreeState="True"
              Width="15" Height="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0"/>
    </Grid>
```

**And here is the Style with triggers:**

```
   <Style x:Key="TogglebuttonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImagePlus}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageMinus}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Content">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageNeutral}"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

**I'll call this a workaround, but now each button retains its own state:**

I found if I moved my Style block out of App.xaml (within the  tag) and defined style triggers for each button, the problem behavior went away.  Since I'm fairly new to WPF/XAML I'm not sure if it's an actual solution or a hacky workaround.  It seems redundant to specify things this way.

```xml
<ToggleButton IsChecked="True" IsThreeState="True"
          Width="25" Height="25" Grid.Row="2" Margin="-1,19,1,-19">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource ImagePlus}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageMinus}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Content">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageNeutral}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```

Comment: I tried the example code you posted and it works as expected. Each button changes separately.

Comment: Still haven't solved the problem, but as one small datapoint I changed the toggle button's content to plain text ("on", "off", "n/a").  All three buttons work independently and maintain their own state.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the setter instantiates one instance of the `Image` control, which can have only one parent. When then button goes into the "ImagePlus" state, all's well. When a second button goes into that state, that `Image` control gets moved to the new parent, leaving the old one bereft.

This is one reason why XAML has templates: When a template is instantiated, a new instance of that snippet of visual tree gets instantiated. Presto, no sharing issues.

With some resources you can set `x:Shared="False"` on the resource and get around this issue. I couldn't find a way to make that work here (I've not yet gotten around to figuring out the principle behind exactly when that works and when not). So I did it with DataTemplates instead:

```
<Style x:Key="TogglebuttonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImagePlus}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageMinus}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{StaticResource ImageNeutral}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation!

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more research, I found I had to specify that the style not be shared.

```xml
<Style x:Key="ToggleButtonStyle" x:Shared="False" /Style>
```